# Hay un máximo de uso de etiquetas input por formulario en HTML?

Tags: php, html, mvc, pdo

En un formulario estoy registrando datos de un cliente, y cada vez que ingreso la dirección del cliente me la guarda con el valor 'Array' como si yo hubiera ingresado eso pero no es así, hice un if para validar si viene vacía o no y resulta que no me está llegando nada desde ese input, adjunto el código de ese input en particular porque es el único que viene vacío, los demás no:

```
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
  <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="direccion" id="direccion" placeholder="Ingrese su dirección">
  <label for="direccion" class="form-label">Dirección</label>
</div>
```

En el controlador, dentro la función de crear que es donde hago la validación para posteriormente enviarla al modelo:

```
public function crear()
{
    if($_POST)
    {
        //si hay un envío post a través del form
        //cada input es asignado a una variable
        $rut=trim($_POST['rut']);
        $nombre=trim($_POST['nombre']);
        $apellidos=trim($_POST['apellidos']);
        $fono=trim($_POST['fono']);
        $direccion=trim(['direccion']);
        $correo=trim($_POST['correo']);
        $patente=trim($_POST['patente']);
        $fecharegistro=$_POST['fecha'];
        if(empty($rut) || empty($nombre) || empty($apellidos) || empty($fono) || empty($direccion) || empty($patente) || empty($fecharegistro))
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">
                Swal.fire({
                      title: "Se encontraron campos vacíos",
                      icon: "error"
                });
            </script>';
        }
        else
        {
            Cliente::crear(strtoupper($rut),ucfirst($nombre),ucfirst($apellidos),$fono,ucfirst($direccion),$correo,strtoupper($patente),$fecharegistro);
        }
    }
    include_once("vistas/clientes/crear.php");
}
```

En la función editar cliente lo tengo exactamente igual, sólo que no edito la fecha en que se registró el usuario y ahí me funciona perfecto, me edita la dirección.

```
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="direccion" class="form-label">Dirección</label>
  <input type="text" required
    class="form-control" value="<?php echo $cliente->direccion?>" name="direccion" id="direccion" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Dirección del cliente">
</div>

public function editar()
{
    if($_POST)
    {
        $rut=trim($_POST['rut']);
        $nombre=trim($_POST['nombre']);
        $apellidos=trim($_POST['apellidos']);
        $fono=trim($_POST['fono']);
        $direccion=trim(['direccion']);
        $correo=trim($_POST['correo']);
        $patente=trim($_POST['patente']);
        //$fecharegistro=$_POST['fecha'];
        if( empty($rut) || empty($nombre) || empty($apellidos) || empty($fono) || empty($direccion) || empty($patente) )
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">
                Swal.fire({
                      title: "Se encontraron campos vacíos",
                      icon: "error"
                });
            </script>';
        }
        else
        {
            Cliente::editar(strtoupper($rut),ucfirst($nombre),ucfirst($apellidos),$fono,ucfirst($direccion),$correo,strtoupper($patente));
        }
    }
    $rut=$_GET['rut'];
    $clientes=Cliente::buscar($rut);
    include_once("vistas/clientes/editar.php");
}
```

Y aquí es donde me pregunto si es que quizás estoy enviando muchos $_POST en un sólo form, existe un máximo de envíos? un mínimo?

Comment: Sólo algunos equipos de seguridad (lee sobre WAF) tienen reglas para filtrar peticiones con más de N elementos en POST. A los demás les da igual (eso sí, los cuerpos de POST tienen tamaños límite, pero son bien altos para tu caso). Por favor incluye en tu pregunta qué es lo que estás viendo al hacer print_r del $_POST (o un var_dump). Que guardes 'Array' significa que estás guardando lo que no es, no que está vacío (sería NULL)

Comment: Gracias por responder, con print_r($_POST['direccion']) me imprime la dirección que ingreso, y con var_dump($direccion) me imprime NULL, pero no entiendo por qué la variable $direccion no guarda el $_POST

Comment: Una vez hice un formulario como con 60 inputs, eran tantos que tuve que crear un generador con `for` y les ponía `name="campo_$i"...` Así estaba diseñada la BD, por lo que tenía que trabajar sobre ese modelo. Era extenso, pero solo se mandaba una vez al día y los operarios tenían toda la jornada para llenarlo, así que no es que fuera tan extenuante tampoco. La cuestión es que el sistema los aceptaba muerto de risa, por lo que en tu caso la cantidad de inputs no es un problema.

Comment: Ya me di cuenta del error, cuando se reescribe mucho código uno no se da cuenta, no editaré la pregunta para que se visualice el error que en $direción me comí el $_POST, y aparece como $direccion=trim(['direccion']);, y lo correcto es $direccion=trim($_POST['direccion']); un capa 8 total